# Running a function multiple times and tracking results of the fight simulation

Tags: ruby

Ive made a function to run a fight simulation. Its got a random element so would like to run it 100 times to check results.

Ive learnt that ruby cant have functions inside functions.

```
$p1_skill = 10
$p1_health = 10

$p2_skill = 10
$p2_health = 10

def hp_check
  if $p2_health >= 1 && $p1_health == 0
    return "p2_wins"
  elsif $p1_health >= 1 && $p2_health == 0
     return "p1_wins"
  else 
    battle
  end
end

def battle
  p1_fight = $p1_skill + rand(2..12)
  p2_fight = $p2_skill + rand(2..12)
  if p1_fight > p2_fight
    $p2_health -= 2
    hp_check
  elsif p2_fight > p1_fight
    $p1_health -= 2
    hp_check
  else
    battle
   end
end

battle
```

Right now this accurately produces a winner. It rolls two dice and adds them to a players skill. If its higher than the other players the other player loses 2 health. 
The skills and hp of players will change throughout the game, this is for a project assignment. 
Id like this to produce odds for win chances for balancing issues.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what is your question? What do you want to achieve? What is your problem? Do you want to run this function multiple time and you don't see how to achieve it? Or, do you have a bug in your function?

Comment: Sorry, first post. 
The above code works if you run it. It will say if player 1 or 2 wins. 50% each because stats are the same currently. 

What I would like is to be able to run this x times and display what % each player won. 
Perhaps each time the above runs it adds to a win counter, but i've already tried that. The main issue is I cant lump the two methods above in an over arching method. 

Summarised. I want to be able to run this 100 times, I then get an output saying player one won 60 times, player 2 won 40 times. *numbers used for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have several suggestions regarding your implementation.  Note that since this is a homework I'm providing the answer in pieces rather than just giving you an entire program.  In no particular order...

1. Don't use global variables.  I suspect this is the major hurdle you're running into with trying to achieve multiple runs of your model.  The model state should be contained within the model methods, and initial state can be passed to it as arguments.  Example:

```
def battle(p1_skill, p1_health, p2_skill, p2_health)
```

2. Unless your instructor has mandated that you use recursion, a simple loop structure will serve you much better.  There's no need to check who won until one player or the other drops down to zero (or lower).  There's also no need for an `else` to recursively call `battle`, the loop will iterate to the next round of the fight if both are still in the running, even if neither player took a hit.

```
while p1_health > 0 && p2_health > 0
  # roll the dice and update health
end
# check who won and return that answer
```

3. `hp_check` really isn't needed, when you lose the recursive calls it becomes a one-liner if you perform the check after breaking out of the loop.  Also, it would be more useful to return just the winner, so whoever gets that return value can decide whether they want to print it, use it to update a tally, both, or something else entirely.  After you break out of the loop outlined above:

```
# determine which player won, since somebody's health dropped to 0 or less
p1_health > 0 ? 1 : 2
```

4. When you're incrementing or decrementing a quantity, don't do equality testing.  `p1_health <= 0` is much safer than `p1_health == 0`, because some day you or somebody else is going to start from an odd number while decrementing by 2's, or decrement by some other (random?) amount.

5. Generating a number uniformly between 2 and 12 is ***not*** the same as summing two 6-sided dice.  There are 36 possible outcomes for the two dice. Only one of the 36 yields a 2, only one yields a 12, and at the other extreme, there are six ways to get a sum of 7.  I created a little die-roll method which takes the number of dice as an argument:

```
def roll_dice(n)
  n.times.inject(0) { |total| total + rand(1..6) }
end
```

so, for example, determining player 1's fight score becomes `p1_fight = p1_skill + roll_dice(2)`.

After making these sorts of changes, tallying up the statistics is pretty straightforward:

```
n = 10000
number_of_p1_wins = 0
n.times { number_of_p1_wins += 1 if battle(10, 10, 10, 10) == 1 }
proportion = number_of_p1_wins.to_f / n
puts "p1 won #{"%5.2f" % (100.0 * proportion)}% of the time"
```

If you replace the constant 10's in the call to `battle` by getting user input or iterating over ranges, you can explore a rich set of other scenarios.